# Como puedo quitar bordes blancos cuando hago scroll lateral en web móvil?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

```css
*{
 top: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}

#container{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 
}


body{
 background: #fff;
 color: black;
 margin-right: 0px;

}

.titulo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.logoescola{
  text-align: right;
}

nav.navbar {
 background-color: #26272b;
}


slide {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-top: 0px;
}

.col-center{
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.noticia {
 background: #fff;
 padding: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-right: 50px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 5px solid #000000;
}

widgets {
 background: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: "Latin Modern Roman 10";
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 150%;
}

.bloc:hover {
 filter: opacity(.5);
}


.site-footer
{
  background-color:#26272b;
  padding:45px 0 20px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:24px;
  color:#737373;
}
.site-footer hr
{
  border-top-color:#bbb;
  opacity:0.5
}
.site-footer hr.small
{
  margin:20px 0
}
.site-footer h6
{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:16px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-top:5px;
  letter-spacing:2px
}
.site-footer a
{
  color:#737373;
}
.site-footer a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links
{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style:none
}
.footer-links li
{
  display:block
}
.footer-links a
{
  color:#737373
}
.footer-links a:active,.footer-links a:focus,.footer-links a:hover
{
  color:#3366cc;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-links.inline li
{
  display:inline-block
}
.site-footer .social-icons
{
  text-align:right
}
.site-footer .social-icons a
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  margin-left:6px;
  margin-right:0;
  border-radius:100%;
  background-color:#33353d
}
.copyright-text
{
  margin:0
}
@media (max-width:991px)
{
  .site-footer [class^=col-]
  {
    margin-bottom:30px
  }
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .site-footer
  {
    padding-bottom:0
  }
  .site-footer .copyright-text,.site-footer .social-icons
  {
    text-align:center
  }
}
.social-icons
{
  padding-left:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  list-style:none
}
.social-icons li
{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:4px
}
.social-icons li.title
{
  margin-right:15px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#96a2b2;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:13px
}
.social-icons a{
  background-color:#eceeef;
  color:#818a91;
  font-size:16px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:44px;
  width:44px;
  height:44px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:8px;
  border-radius:100%;
  -webkit-transition:all .2s linear;
  -o-transition:all .2s linear;
  transition:all .2s linear
}
.social-icons a:active,.social-icons a:focus,.social-icons a:hover
{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#29aafe
}
.social-icons.size-sm a
{
  line-height:34px;
  height:34px;
  width:34px;
  font-size:14px
}
.social-icons a.facebook:hover
{
  background-color:#3b5998
}
.social-icons a.twitter:hover
{
  background-color:#00aced
}
.social-icons a.linkedin:hover
{
  background-color:#007bb6
}
.social-icons a.dribbble:hover
{
  background-color:#ea4c89
}
@media (max-width:767px)
{
  .social-icons li.title
  {
    display:block;
    margin-right:0;
    font-weight:600
  }
}

.llistablocs {
  list-style:none;
}

.aprop {
 text-align: center;
}

div.row{
  margin-right: 0px;
}

div.container-fluid{
  padding-right: 0px;
}

div.container{
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Estoy creando una web con html, css y bootstrap y la he subido a un servidor para hacer pruebas.
Des del navegador la visualización es correcta, cuando la veo con chrome en el modo móvil también se ve correctamente.
El problema es cuando la abro desde mi móvil. En un primer momento se ve correctamente, pero aparece una barra de scroll debajo y cuando desplazo hacia los laterales se queda un espacio blanco en la parte derecha.
Además, cuando la veo en horizontal desde el móvil se ven bordes blancos a los lados.
Adjunto imágenes.
Muchísimas gracias por las respuestas.

[image: horizontal]

[image: vertical móvil]

[image: vertical móvil2]

Código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
 <title>Escola Francesc Platón i Sartí</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark">
    <!-- Nos permite usar el componente collapse para dispositivos moviles -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Menu de Navegacion">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="titulo">
     <h5>Escola Francesc Platón i Sartí</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="row collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar"> 
     
     <div class="col">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
       <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Inici <span class="sr-only">(Actual)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="menu-categorias" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Blog
       </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-categorias">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">HTML</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">CSS</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">JS</a>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="contacta.html" class="nav-link">Contacta</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </div>

     <div class="col logoescola align-self-start">
      <img src="logos/logoplaton.png" alt="Logo Escola" width="120" height="150" /></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   
  </nav>

  <slide class="row">
   <div class="col-9 col-center">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="principal-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#principal-carousel" data-slid-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#principal-carousel" data-slid-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#principal-carousel" data-slid-to="2"></li>
     </ol>

     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
       <img src="img/carousel1.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
       <img src="img/carousel2.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
       <img src="img/carousel3.jpg" class="w-100" alt="">
      </div>
     </div>

     <a href="#principal-carousel" class="carousel-control-prev" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
     </a>

     <a href="#principal-carousel" class="carousel-control-next" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </slide>

  <hr>
  <section class="row">
   <hr>
    <div class="noticia col">
     <h2>Notícies d'interés</h2>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <hr>
  <footer class="site-footer">
   <div class="container">



     <div class="row">
      
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
     <h6 class="aprop">Els blocs</h6>
     <div class="aprop llistablocs">
      <p>Infantil</p>
      <p>Primer A B</p> <!--<a class="logoa" title="a" href="http://www.google.es"><img  src="logos/a.png" alt="a" width="20" height="20" /></a> -->
      <p>Segon A B</p>
      <p>Tercer A B C</p>
      <p>Quart A B C</p>
      <p>Cinquè A B C</p>
      <p>Sisè A B C</p>
     </div>
      </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <h6 class="aprop">Troba'ns</h6>
      <p class="aprop"> Carrer Salvador Espriu, 3 <br> 08630 Abrera <br> Telèfon: 937 70 03 81 <br> E-mail: a8000013@xtec.cat </p>
      <p align="center"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2987.523982641834!2d1.8987473154297378!3d41.51458927925275!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x12a48bee0086ffe7%3A0xc5eacea406a09a17!2sCEIP%20Francesc%20Plat%C3%B3n%20i%20Sarti!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1591028363079!5m2!1ses!2ses" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe></p>
    </div>
   
    


     </div>



     <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p class="aprop">Una mica més a prop de nosaltres...</p>
    </div>
   
     </div>
   </div>
   </footer>
 </div>
 
 <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

He añadido también el css.
Es curioso porqué el problema solo aparece cuando la ejecuto desde el móvil.
En el navegador perfecto incluso poniendo la pantalla en modo móvil.

Os dejo el enlace a la web:
http://agui.tonohost.com/

el problema lo veréis abriendo el link desde un móvil.

Comment: Hola, comparte el codigo HTML para poder ver las etiquetas y clases ya que si usas bootstraps es posible que sea un problema de `col-md-x` o a fin.

Comment: He editado con el código html.

Comment: Para que nosotros podamos ver lo mismo que tú, tendrías que poner el link correcto a las hojas de estilos de CSS. Así como lo agregaste, no vemos el problema que mencionas.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente se ha solucionado con el siguiente código en css:

```css
div.row{
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin: 0px!important;
}



div.container-fluid{
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

div.container{
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Gracias a todos!!!

Comment: Dudo que ese haya sido el error, esas clases son de Bootstrap y no deberías modificarlas, pues funcionan como deben, a lo mejor con eso solo "tapaste" otro error dentro de tu estructura.